# Modify existing MS Access Query via ODBC

Tags: python, ms-access, odbc, arcmap, pypyodbc

I have a python script that update and generates exports in ArcMap. The ArcMap document pulls data to be mapped from MS Access. Currently, I have to go into to MS Access and update the criteria for a date from/to column (in design view) and save it before running the script to generate exports. I would like to be able to simply update the date range in the criteria box, save the query, and close the connection.

I have tried to using SQL Update strings, but I get errors for too few arguments and I don't want it to create or change the any tables. Only the query in my database.

```
db = pypyodbc.connect(
r"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"+
    r"Dbq=P:\path\path\path.mdb;")

sql = """SELECT DISTINCT"""

db.cursor().execute(sql).commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a saved query in Access via ODBC we can use a `CREATE VIEW` statement, e.g.,

```python
crsr.execute("CREATE VIEW CAD_Extract_Mapping AS SELECT ...")
```

Unfortunately, Access SQL does not support `ALTER VIEW`, and `DROP VIEW` also doesn't work. However, the workaround is to use `DROP TABLE view_name`, e.g.,

```python
crsr.execute("DROP TABLE CAD_Extract_Mapping")
crsr.execute("CREATE VIEW CAD_Extract_Mapping AS SELECT ...")
```

Note that many DDL commands will fail to execute from within a transaction, so you may need to use

```python
cnxn.autocommit = True
```

before trying the above.